# Issue with the ClassLoader of ProcessingEnvironment from Maven

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, maven, classloader

I'm new to maven, and barely handling the concept of ClassLoader. 
Working on a project, I got this problem. 
I have a code generator, which revises a class to be a certain way (JavaBean) using the Java Compiler API. My problem is, it works perfectly when I run it from Eclipse, but when I do from Maven gives me some errors. It says can not convert from a com.sun.source.util.Trees com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTrees

I think the problem is the inconsistency in the ClassLoader because I print on screen the value of ClassLoader: is correct from Eclipse, but when I run in Maven changes the ClassLoader of ProcessingEnvironment

this is where I write annotations processor. The error is right on the line where I instantiate the processingEnv to trees.

Attempt to force the ClassLoader processingEnv be the same as tree (com.sun.source.util.Trees) but just does not work from Maven

```
public class AnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

private Trees trees;
  @Override
  public void init(ProcessingEnvironment processingEnv) {
   super.init(processingEnv);

   System.out.println("getClass().getClassLoader(): "
     + getClass().getClassLoader().toString());
   System.out.println("Trees.class.getClassLoader(): "
     + Trees.class.getClassLoader().toString());
   System.out.println("processingEnv.getClass().getClassLoader() 1: "
     + processingEnv.getClass().getClassLoader().toString());

   try {
    processingEnv.getClass().getClassLoader()
      .loadClass("com.sun.source.util.Trees");
    trees = Trees.instance(processingEnv);

    System.out.println("processingEnv.getClass().getClassLoader() 2: "
      + processingEnv.getClass().getClassLoader().toString());
   } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Part of the error I get in the console is:

```
getClass().getClassLoader(): ClassRealm[plugin>com.minotauro:CledaPropMaven:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@60396ed8]
Trees.class.getClassLoader(): ClassRealm[plugin>com.minotauro:CledaPropMaven:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@60396ed8]
processingEnv.getClass().getClassLoader() 1: java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader@554f686d
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.179s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Aug 03 19:31:27 VET 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/98M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.minotauro:CledaPropMaven:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:propDesc (default-cli) on project CledaMavenTest: Execution default-cli of goal com.minotauro:CledaPropMaven:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:propDesc failed: java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTrees cannot be cast to com.sun.source.util.Trees -> [Help 1]
```

Please! I need help! Thank you!
Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, the problem was associated with using the JDK's [`ToolProvider`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/ToolProvider.html) to get an instance of [`JavaCompiler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html). The `ToolProvider` ends up using a different classloader to load the `com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool` class.

The solution that worked for me (at least so far) was instead of using the `getSystemJavaCompiler` method to provide an instance of `JavaCompiler`:

```
  JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
```

I just `create`d a compiler using `JavacTool.create()`:

```
  JavaCompiler compiler = JavacTool.create();
```

Of course, this ties you to that specific implementation, but (personally) I'm willing to live with that for now.